# Charting without using controller action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, mschart

I know how to chart by using a Controller action that returns `FileResult`.

My question is, is it possible to move the action into the view (cshtml) file as a helper? This way the view logic is entirely contained in the view.

The problem is, without a Controller action, what URL can I fill in the `img src` attribute? Or is there a different way, instead of `img` tag, to display the image stream?

Comment: @James The question is how to direct the stream into the img src attribute? As a controller action there is a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the core problem is that you want to load image data without a url (whether that url points to a `Controller`, or some static resource), you can dump the image data directly to the html using `base64` embedding as follows:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EmbedImageWithBase64(this HtmlHelper helper, byte[] imageBytes)
        {
        var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        var imageSrcData = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data;
        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<img alt="Chart Data" src=\"{1}\" />", imageSrcData));
        }
```

Comment: Please note that if you chart image format is other that `png` you'll have to change it of course.